# Is there a way to update a TextBox when is not visible?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a TextBox nested inside a TabControl.

Form->TabControl1->TabPage1->TabControl2->TabpPage2->GroupBox->TextBox

When the TabPage1, TabPage2 is selected, so the TextBox is visible to the user all the TextBoxEvents works OK, but when the user selects another TabPage it doesn't work.
I have a timer that send data periodically to know if an external device is present on a specific virtual COM port.
When the external device answer I put that data in that TextBox and set a global flag(boolean) to let the rest of the program that a device is present.
I'm processing the received data on a Private Sub and changing that TextBox with a Lambda expression like this

```
Me.Invoke(Sub()
               Me.VersionFirmwareTxt.Text = RespX.Substring(5)
               End Sub)
```

Comment: Make sure that the Controls in TabPages not yet shown create their handles. You can loop the `Controls` collection of affected TabPages and call `CreateControl()` on each. It may work simply calling `CreateControl()` on the TabPage itself (depending on the Framework version).

Comment: The Framework is 4.5, I think.

Comment: Then loop the Controls collection of the nested GroupBox and call `CreateControl()` on its child controls: `[SomeGroupBox].Controls.OfType(Of Control)().ToList().ForEach(sub(c) c.CreateControl())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the TextBox by name from anywhere whether it is visible or not, via casting (CType), and update its text value using the syntax:

```
'(from within the same Form, e.g., Form1)
    
CType(TabControl1.TabPages(1).Controls("VersionFirmwareTxt"), TextBox).Text = RespX.Substring(5)
    
    
'(from a different Form)
    
CType(Form1.TabControl1.TabPages(1).Controls("VersionFirmwareTxt"), TextBox).Text = RespX.Substring(5)
```

If you dynamically added the TextBox to the controls of the parent (TabPage), you will know exactly where the TextBox is located, since you would have already used, e.g.:

```
TabControl1.TabPages(1).Controls.Add(VersionFirmwareTxt)
```

Whereas if you manually added the TextBox to the TabPage, you also know the parent control.